# parsing XML files using java- null pointer exception

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Hi everyone i'm trying to parse xml files using java using code below..

```
try{

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBulider=docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document config_doc=docBulider.parse("config/appconfig.xml");
        config_doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
       Node n =config_doc.getDocumentElement();
      NodeList list= n.getChildNodes();
      for(int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
          System.out.print(list.item(i));
        if(list.item(i).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("version-name")){
         name=list.item(i).getNodeValue();
        }

      }

        }
        catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

My file layout is like this

[image: File Layout]

I keep getting file not found exception. I also used

> getClass().getResouce("config/appconfig.xml").toExternalForm()

and i tried to read as stream too.

Thank you :)

Comment: Re: File not found. Where is the file? Inside your classpath? Or relative to the current working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one seems good

`getClass().getResouce("config/appconfig.xml").toExternalForm()`

except that it is `main/config/appconfig.xml`

Comment: Or rather /main/config/appconfig.xml

Answer (score 1):

Try using

Sytsem.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

This will print out your program's current working directory, then you can figure out the relative path to your appconfig.xml file.

Good luck

Piers

Comment: I think problem is because file is being archieved inside Jar file

Answer (score 0):

You can give the absolute path as :

```
Document config_doc=docBulider.parse(new File("$Absolute Path of the file"));
```